# How can I prevent label trunc on chartjs?

Tags: vue.js, chart.js

I genere a donut chart using chartjs and clivuejs.
My problem is depending on the chart the external label can be truncate or not.

Using "inspect" chrome mode I tried to amend the width/height of the canvas and of different parent div without.

```
//../src/DoughnutChart.js

import {
    Doughnut,mixins
} from 'vue-chartjs'

export default {
  extends: Doughnut,
    mixins: [mixins.reactiveProp],
    props: ['chartData'],
    data() {
        return {
            options: {
                tooltips: {
                  enabled: true
                },
                pieceLabel: {
                  render: 'label',
                  arc: true,
                  fontColor: '#000',
                  position: 'inside'
                },
                responsive: true,
                legend: {
                  display: false,
                  position: 'top',
                },
                scaleLabel : {
                    display: true
                  },
                maintainAspectRatio: false
            }
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.renderChart(this.chartdata, this.options)
    }

}
```

As you can see on attached file, external labels are not visible at all or truncate.

[image]

EDIT:
Using padding advise provided by Daniel (thanks Daniel)I have now the following. Event if the chart is very small I still have the issue. Is there any way to force the label to have a smarter position based on parent canvas ?
[image]

Comment: Have you looked into setting appropriate layout padding to ensure you have enough spacing always? https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/layout.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer this help.But even if set a big padding I still have the issue because the label are far from the donuts and my donuts is very small compare to the canvas.
Is their any way to force exertnal label to have a smarter position ?